# Yii2 model public attributes

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a User model with some attributes that are public and some that are db column attributes

Assume that the model have N many public attributes (Email and Surname for example) and column attributes (Salt, confirmation_token for example)

I want to loop through all attributes in a model including **public attributes** and **db column attributes**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your User model is an `ActiveRecord` you can create a function like this to retrieve the combination of the public attributes and the ones retrieved from the database.

```
public function getAllAttributes() {
    return array_merge(
        parent::attributes(),
        \yii\base\Model::attributes()
    );
}
```

Printing the values of the attributes can then be done like

```
$attributes = $model->getAllAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    echo $model->$attribute;
    echo "<br />";
}
```